# Why did my root change to -bash-4.1?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, ssh

My root@servername automatically changed to -bash-4.1@servername in one of the servers.

I have the same .bashrc on both servers.
Also when I do echo $PS1 I get the following, and it's the same on both servers

```
echo $PS1
[\u@\h \W]\$
```

So I am not sure what changed it.

Comment: and... you're programming what? - Try Unix & Linux: http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If you told us your distro/flavour of unix we might be able to give more specific responses as to where to look .... generic ideas: check ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login and ~/.login for details. You may of course have broken a system wide file inadvertently - have you checked the prompt as your normal user (I hope you have a normal account to get onto your servers ... )?

Comment: Have you checked if PROMPT_COMMAND is set?

Answer (score -2):

Check `/root/.bashrc` and `/etc/bashrc` as the likely source of the PS1 setting for a root `login`/`su`

Comment: He **had** checked ~/.bashrc. And his distro may not have /etc/bashrc ...

Comment: Without knowing the distro, it seemed helpful to make suggestions as to where to look.  I explicitly expanded the notion of `~` to be `/root`, again as a suggestion, because it is easy to think of "~" as one's own home directory and not the one you just `su`'d into.